# How do I grab text from XML between two characters in Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have a large file I would like to parse and grab select snippets of text from. Here is an actual sample from the file:

```
en-US   AcceptedText pt="dial:def"Tag u="contact"Mom/Tag/AcceptedText 11373
```

The snippet of text I would like to grab is between the first `"` and `:`. In the case above, it would be the word `dial`.

Here is the script I have put together:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (SESAME, '/home/my_name/whereMyFileLives.txt');
while (<SESAME>) {
  $text .= $_;
}
close (SESAME);

$text =~ /\n*$/;
$text =~ m/ \" (.*) :> /;

print $text;
```

When I run this script, it prints the file to the terminal exactly as the file already was. It does not parse the text and extract the snippets of text I would like it to extract..

Any pointers?

Comment: Since your input is XML data it cannot look like the sample that you show, as that isn't valid XML. And you shouldn't be processing XML using regexes: It's a lot simpler and safer if you use a library devoted to the task. If you post more of your *actual* data, showing it in context, then you will get much better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Can't understand why are you doing that first match with `\n`, but for your task you can do it like this:

```
my ($result) = $text =~ /\"([^:]*):/;
```

Comment: I'm still learning perl, so I am probably wrong, but did the first match with \n to try and rid the file of any loose new lines hanging around.

I tried replacing the line $text=~m/ \" (.*) :> /; with the line you provided above ( ($text) =~ /\"([^:]*):/;

but when the script reaches the print $text line, the output to the terminal still consists of the file as is, rather than the snippets of text i am looking to extract..

Sorry if I am bungling things!! Should I be placing the results into a separate variable?

Comment: It is a bad idea to encourage the use of regexes to process XML. It is fraught with problems, and Perl has several good XML libraries.

Comment: @user1849737: The answer Rohit gave you doesn't change `$text`, it just extracts the section of the string you wanted and puts it into `$result`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my ($string) = $text =~ /"(.*?):/;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------

use charnames qw( :full :short );
use English qw( -no_match_vars ) ;  # Avoids regex performance penalty

# open (SESAME, '/home/my_name/whereMyFileLives.txt');
#
# Please use the three-argument open
my $sesame_file = '/home/my_name/whereMyFileLives.txt';
open my $sesame_fh, '<', $sesame_file or die "could not open $sesame_file: $OS_ERROR\n";

# while(<SESAME>)
while( my $line = <$sesame_fh> ){

# {
# $text .= $_;
# }
# close (SESAME);
# $text=~/\n*$/;
# $text=~m/ \" (.*) :> /;
# print $text;
#
# No need to store the complete text, just extract what you want from each line
    if( $line =~ m{ \" ( [^:]* ) \: }msx ){
        my $snippet = $1;
        print "$snippet\n";
    } # end if

} # end while
close $sesame_fh or die "could not close $sesame_file: $OS_ERROR\n";
```